# Android Studio - Rebuild Project - Could not download aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows.jar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, aapt2

This is the configuration I have on my project:

- Android Studio 4.1 (September 23, 2020)
- Android Gradle Plugin Version 4.1.0
- Gradle Version 6.7
- Compile SDK 29 (Android 10.0 Q)
- Build Tools 29.0.2
- Min Sdk 17
- Target Sdk 26 (Android 8.0 Oreo)

In the build.gradle of the project I have

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
....
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

When I use the "Build> Rebuild Project" command in Build Output I get this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
Could not download aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.0-6503028): No cached version available for offline mode

Possible solution:
 - Disable offline mode and rerun the build
```

- I tried with the "Toggle Offline Mode" in the Gradle panel (both to set it and to remove it), but the error still occurs.
- I tried to clean the whole .gradle folder but same result.
- I also created an emulator with API 30 because they suggested it would download the missing package, but it didn't change the situation.
- I tried to manually download the jar (https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=aapt2#com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.0-6503028) and put it in libs, but the error still comes out.

Comment: I am facing the same issue any ideas why it should happen?

Answer (score 7):

A month too late for this, but I was also getting a similar error with not being able to download aapt2, but for a different version number.

Turns out, the order of the `google()` dependency mattered as mentioned here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#aapt2_gmaven

So everywhere you are adding the dependency for `google()` move it up, and it should work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

copy this

```
 implementation 'com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.0-6503028'
```

in Gradle in the Android Studio after that click Sync Now after finished   click run to try

Comment: I tried and the Sync works fine, but then the "Rebuild> Project" command still shows the same error.